# How to completely rebuild a project in react native?

Tags: react-native

There is quite a lot of code.  The app started and ran well.  But after trying to set up files in the Android and iOS folders, the application stopped compiling.  These folders were not in git.  And there is no way to return the original text of the configuration files.  Attempts to restore functionality were unsuccessful.  How to re-initialize the project so that the Android and iOS folders are re-created?

Comment: Are yu using version control like Git ?

Comment: Yes, but this folders in .gitignore (((